# How do I pass a 'null' action

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following function definition

```
private void DoExport(Action<ColumnView, bool> UpdateColumns)  
{  
...  
}

private void UpdateNonPrintableColumns(ColumnView view, bool visible)  
{  
...  
}
```

Example of it being called:

```
DoExport(UpdateNonPrintableColumns);
```

My question is. How do I pass a 'null' action? Is it even possible?

e.g.
<del>`DoExport(null);  <- Throws exception`</del>

DoExport(null) causes an exception to be thrown when the action gets called in the function body

Comment: On a related note, you may need to cast the null in some circumstances, e.g. 
Action a = someCond? MyMethod : (Action)null;

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pass in an empty action if you want to:

```
DoExport((x, y) => { })
```

Second, you have to review your code, since passing in `null` is perfectly fine.

```
public void X()
{
    A(null);
}

public void A(Action<ColumnView, bool> a)
{
    if (a != null)
    {
        a();
    }
}
```

Or as per C# 6 (using the null-propagation operator):

```
public void A(Action<ColumnView, bool> a)
{
    a?.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error 19 Delegate 'System.Action<DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView,bool>' does not take 0 arguments

Comment: I updated and tested my answer. It does work. If you have additional parameters, add them in the lamdba constructor.

Comment: vs2015 recommends `a?.Invoke();`

Answer (score 9):

You can pass an action that does nothing:

```
DoExport((_, __) => { });
```

Comment: Double wow! +1 just for this awesome answer. May I ask where in the c# specification (or wherever) did you find out that one can use _ as a variable?

Comment: I would vote this as my accepted answer, but I'm just concerned that whoever maintains the code won't know what the heck _ is about

Comment: @Eminem The spec is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx) - '_' can be used as a starting character,  but there's no requirement to follow it with anything. I find it useful in lambdas to show which variables (if any) are being effectively being ignored. Also, that's fair enough - Patrick's answer is more rounded - the null check is important.

Comment: The underscores come from functional programming where they generally mean, "don't care about this."

Comment: The worst possible combination of 10 ugly tokens to declare something simple as "empty"...

Answer (score 2):

Or just handle it inside of the method:

```
private void DoExport(Action<ColumnView, bool> UpdateColumns)  
{  
  if (UpdateColumns != null)
    UpdateColumns(...);
}
```

Comment: Duh! moment by me. Should have checked for null... +1

Answer (score -1):

I think the most elegant answer is more or less part of the original question. Just add a `private static` callback that does nothing:

```cs
private static void EmptyCallback(ColumnView _, bool _)
{
}
```

Then, when calling the method, your intension gets pretty clear. And there will be no doubt what the compiler does under the hood (e.g. delegate allocations):

```cs
DoExport(EmptyCallback);
```